# Jquery Validation - Custom Method > determine whether any one of a set of radio buttons are checked

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, radio-button

I have a group of radio buttons in a form, when certain buttons are checked, some additional fields are displayed and validation needs to be added. I am trying to do this by setting validation rules with conditions, using a custom method. Note :- Only one Radio button out of the group can be checked at one time ( this behaviour is handled elsewhere )

**Define the radio buttons to trigger the display of additional fields :-**

```
showEmployerDetails = $("#employerType_0,#employerType_2,#employerType_8,#employerType_4,#employerType_8,#employerType_6,#employerType_5");

employerInital = showEmployerDetails.is(":checked");
```

*NB :- These variables are used else where in the script to perform some show / hide behaviour, so I am keen not to redefine elsewhere.*

**Custom Method**

```
$.validator.addMethod("employdetailsreq", function(value) {
return employerInital;
}, "Please supply details");
```

**Validation Rules**

```
$("#myform_1").validate({
        rules: {
        field1: {employdetailsreq : true },
        field2: {employdetailsreq : true },
        field3: {employdetailsreq : true },
        field4: {employdetailsreq : true },
        field5: {employdetailsreq : true }
        }

                });
```

My aim was for the variable "*employerInital*" to return true or false, if ANY of the radio buttons are checked. Needless to say, this is not working. I think I am over complicating things.

**Additional query :-**

I have other rules ( omitted here for clarity ) that look like this :-

```
field__238: {required: "#vehicleuse_1:checked" },
```

Can I do something like :-

```
field1: {required:  "employdetailsreq : true" }
```

Or is this exactly the same as :-

```
field1: { employdetailsreq : true }
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable only contains a value, it's no bound to the properties that were used to calculate the value, so it won't change its value when any of the checkboxes are checked or unchecked. You have to recheck the checkboxes to get the current status:

```
$.validator.addMethod("employdetailsreq", function(value) {
  return showEmployerDetails.is(":checked");
}, "Please supply details");
```

Comment: Thanks @Guffa. I've tried that, but it's still not doing the validation, although it is returning 'true', when one of the buttons is checked, I think I am declaring the rule incorrectly - Can I do something like :-

`code`field1: {required:  "employdetailsreq : true" }`code`

Or is this exactly the same as :-

`code`field1: { employdetailsreq : true }`code`

Comment: Yes, I think this works :-

`code` field1: {required: { employdetailsreq : true }},`code` I was missing the extra set of curly brackets